# Remove a special character that exists between 2 characters

Tags: abap

I have the following string:
**6103951001#136,00#S0#0#99999999#8000010000#10.12.2019#
31.10.2019#"MATZOURAKIS IOANNISMROA118#OSPh"#99470##APE A   54226#K**
What I want is to delete the special character HORIZONTAL_TAB(#) which is between " here is the part of the string: **"MATZOURAKIS IOANNISMROA118#OSPh"**
How can I do?
Thanks

PS. I am using the following to upload the data from a TAB delimited text file
data: data_table type standard table of char255,

```
        wa_data_table like line of data_table.

  lv_file = p_file.
  cl_gui_frontend_services=>gui_upload(
    exporting
      filename                = lv_file
      filetype                = 'ASC'
    changing
      data_tab                = data_table
```

Now I am doing the following in order to catch the problem

```
  loop at data_table into wa_data_table.
    find all occurrences of '"' in wa_data_table match count lv_count.
    if sy-subrc = 0 and lv_count = 2.
*      REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX
*      '(#(?=[^"]*"[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$))' IN wa_data_table WITH ' '.
      split wa_data_table at '"'
                            into split_data1 split_data2 split_data3.
      replace all occurrences of cl_abap_char_utilities=>horizontal_tab
             in split_data2 with ' '.
      concatenate split_data1 split_data2 split_data3
                                                  into wa_data_table.
    endif.
endloop.
```

I think that we must handle the cl_abap_char_utilities=>horizontal_tab not with the character # but in another way.

Comment: have a look at REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX.

Comment: What I was looking was to tell the program to remove the HORIZONTAL_TAB that is between the ". Unfortunately, I couldn't find. So I check each record and if I find that there are 2 " I am splitting into 3 variables and remove the HORIZONTAL_TAB from the 2nd and finally I Concatenate the 3 variable to the WA. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following in ABAP to find this character and replace it:

```
data : lv_test type string VALUE '6103951001#136,00#S0#0#99999999#8000010000#10.12.2019# 31.10.2019#"MATZOURAKIS IOANNISMROA118#OSPh"#99470##APE A 54226#K'.

REPLACE ALL OCCURRENCES OF REGEX '(#(?=[^"]*"[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$))' IN lv_test WITH ''.
write lv_test.
```

This is the correct solution for this problem.

```
  replace all occurrences of regex
                    '(\t(?=[^"]*"[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$))'
                    in table data_table with ' '.
  replace all occurrences of regex '["]' in table data_table with ''.
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it today or tomorrow. Can someone explain me the REGEX (#(?=[^"]*"[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$))?

Comment: go to this site: https://regex101.com/. copy the regex in there and on the right it will give you the explanation (it's a bit much to type out in the comments). @ekekakos

Comment: @ekekakos I tested it myseld I created in se38 a new program and just pasted that code in there and executed it without problem. We are using BW 7.4.

Comment: These data are coming from uploading a TAB delimited text file. I just copy the data from the ITAB that I use to upload the data.

Comment: @ekekakos ok, so you can't put that string from your ITAB into a variable and run my code on it?

Comment: Well I found the answer to my problem. As I told you this is a TAB character which is displayed as # by SAP. So we have to replace the # with \t, so the regex will be done: '(\t(?=[^"]*"[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$))'. This works fine. Thanks a lot.